# bluepy.btle.BTLEException: Failed to execute mgmt cmd 'scanend'

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
devices = scanner.scan(arg.timeout)
self._mgmtCmd(self._cmd()+"end")
```

> Failed to execute mgmt cmd '%s'" % (cmd))
>   bluepy.btle.BTLEException: Failed to execute mgmt cmd 'scanend'

Comment: if i get it right, you only gave a traceback and error message. i would assume the code is also required to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "fix" for this which appears to be a race condition between subsequent invocations of "bluepy-helper"..

```
diff --git a/bluepy/btle.py b/bluepy/btle.py
index ec950e1..65e6a78 100755
--- a/bluepy/btle.py
+++ b/bluepy/btle.py
@@ -218,6 +218,7 @@ class BluepyHelper:
             self._helper.stdin.write("quit\n")
             self._helper.stdin.flush()
             self._helper.wait()
+            time.sleep(0.1)
             self._helper = None
         if self._stderr is not None:
             self._stderr.close()
```

https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy/issues/150

Comment: Don't know if it really helps. I added the 0.1 seconds sleep as suggested. When I restarted my python script, I still got the same error. Then I restarted the system and the problem was solved. So I don't know whether restarting would have solved the issue anyways OR if the change in the lib was not pulled in before after the restart of the system..?